# Inkscape won't open

Tags: ubuntu, inkscape

I have tried installing Inkscape through both the terminal, app grid, synaptic and using the .deb file. Also, I have tried both the 32 and 64 bit versions. The icon appears but when I try to launch it the loader spins for a while but then stops and it stops running. Strangely, it does not appear in the system monitor and no windows appear although if I right-click the icon it does give the option to create a new drawing(the button does not work though).

Comment: the output was:$ inkscape
inkscape: error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: On what version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 was not installed. this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/inkscape/+bug/842564) and was solved by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:i386 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
```